# Override React OnClick event for 300ms delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React app I have several components which implement onClick handlers. The problem is I'm deploying to Safari on an Ipad, so there is a 300ms delay on click. What is the best way to remove this delay? Is it possible to override React onClick listener or something similar? I'm aware of several repo's trying to fix this but I can't add new methods, I just need the original onClick to work. Also I'm aware of [react-fastclick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fastclick) but it doesn't work with React 0.14

Answer (score 2):

The 300ms delay is a javascript thing in general that mobile devices have. [This link](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/) tells you a ton of ways to get around it. I've had great success listening for `touchend` events instead of `click` because touch events have no delay.

Other workarounds include:

1. Disable Zooming (Chrome and Firefox) by adding a meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`
2. Set the viewport to the device-width (Chrome 32+) `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=3">`
3. use this non-standard PointerEvents workaround (for IE)

   a, button, .myelements
   {
       -ms-touch-action: manipulation; /* IE10  */
       touch-action: manipulation;     /* IE11+ */
   }

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm specifically targeting Safari on mobile

Comment: did you try `touchend`? there is no delay in safari for these events.

Comment: Are you suggesting digging into React onClick handler to add a touchend? That's the thing, I don't want to bind more handlers. I just want to extend the onClick functionality globally, without editing every single file

Comment: As of iOS 9.3 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` works for Safari as well.